# Pandas how to copy a column to another dataframe with similar index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one Pandas dataframe like below. I used `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.normalize()` to get the date2 column to show just the date and ignore the time. Wasn't sure how to have it be just YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
                       date2  count  compound_mean
0  2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00     18       0.188411
1  2021-01-02 00:00:00+00:00      9       0.470400
2  2021-01-03 00:00:00+00:00     10       0.008190
3  2021-01-04 00:00:00+00:00     58       0.187510
4  2021-01-05 00:00:00+00:00    150       0.176173
```

Another dataframe with the following format.

```
Date          Average
2021-01-04    18.200001
2021-01-05    22.080000
2021-01-06    22.250000
2021-01-07    22.260000
2021-01-08    21.629999
```

I want to have the `Average` column show up in the first dataframe by matching the dates and then forward-filling any blank values. From 01-01 to 01-03 there will be nothing to forward fill, so I guess it will end up being zero. I'm having trouble finding the right Pandas functions to do this, looking for some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date` to just get the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your first dataframe to be df1 and second dataframe to be df2.

Firstly, you need to change the name of the date2 column of df1 to Date so that it matches with your Date column of df2.

```py
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date2']).dt.date
```

You can then remove the date2 column of df1 as

```py
df1.drop("date2",inplace=True, axis=1)
```

You also need to change the column type of Date of df2 so that it matches with type of df1's Date column

```py
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.date
```

Then make a new dataframe which will contain both dataframe columns based on Date column.

```py
main_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on="Date", how="left")
df1['Average'] = main_df['Average']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns = ['Date', 'count','compound_mean','Average'])
```

You can then fill the null values by ffill and also the first 3 null values by 0

```py
df1.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Your first dataframe will look what you wanted

Comment: Thank you, Prakash, for the explanation of what each step does. This achieved what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
>>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date2).dt.date 
# If df.date2 is already datetime, use ^ df.index = df.date2.dt.date
>>> df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) 
# If df2['Date'] is already datetime, ^ this above line is not needed
>>> df.join(df2.set_index('Date')).fillna(0)
                                date2  count  compound_mean    Average
date2                                                                 
2021-01-01  2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00     18       0.188411   0.000000
2021-01-02  2021-01-02 00:00:00+00:00      9       0.470400   0.000000
2021-01-03  2021-01-03 00:00:00+00:00     10       0.008190   0.000000
2021-01-04  2021-01-04 00:00:00+00:00     58       0.187510  18.200001
2021-01-05  2021-01-05 00:00:00+00:00    150       0.176173  22.080000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) operation as follows:

```
#Making date of same UTC format from both tables
df1['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date2'],utc = True)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'],utc = True)

#Renaming df1 column so that we can map 'Date' from both dataframes
df1.rename(columns={'date2': 'Date'},inplace=True)

#Merge operation
res = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Date',how='left').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
Date    count   compound_mean   Average
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00   18  0.188411    0.000000
1   2021-01-02 00:00:00+00:00   9   0.470400    0.000000
2   2021-01-03 00:00:00+00:00   10  0.008190    0.000000
3   2021-01-04 00:00:00+00:00   58  0.187510    18.200001
4   2021-01-05 00:00:00+00:00   150 0.176173    22.080000
```